# Numbers of participants in crowdsourcing tasks

Tags: dataset, data-analysis

Within the recent years, leveraging crowdsourcing for performing, mainly intelligent-intensive, tasks has become prevalent. An important question in this regard, that I could not find any specific answer for, is how many participants are adequate for running such a project? Is there any standard for that?

Answer (score 0):

The number of participants vary widely based the difficulty of the problem.

Generally, people start with a pilot number of participants have them complete the task. Make sure the project is working end-to-end and is moving towards the goal. Then increase the number of participants until the goal is accomplished or the diminishing returns are not worth the value.